# How to set php cookie via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've done a little browsing on this site regarding this topic. And found out that its possible to set php cookies via ajax. 
But I don't know why I can't set cookies on an ajax called php script. I even set a default value, just to make sure that the cookie is getting something:

```
setcookie("tradename", 'mono', time()+3600);    
setcookie("bus_id", 'loque', time()+3600);
```

The ajax called php script has mysql queries on it. And they're inserting records into the database. The setting of cookies happens before the queries.

But I don't know why I'm not getting anything when I use print_r from another page:

```
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

I'm using jquery's ajax() function. What do I do to detect what's wrong, please help. Thanks.

Comment: please comment if you need more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need ajax to set cookies from js. Look at "jquery cookie" plugin [here](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), maybe you will like it. Example usage is at the top of jquery.cookie.js.